# How to extract the fragment between the body (<body>...</body>) tags from AJAX response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

An AJAX response is returning the full HTML page. I need to extract the fragment between the body (`<body>` and `</body>`) tags. This is required to be done on the client side using JavaScript. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any javascript library, or vanilla javascript?

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. For now, we took the substring approach since we know the exact format of the HTML being returned (we are generating it ourselves). I shall lookup YQL as a general technology for this kind of requirements.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest but kind-of worst way would be simple string hacking on the response text.

```
var bodyhtml= html.split('<body>').pop().split('</body>')[0];
```

This is unsatisfactory in the general case, but can be feasible if you know the exact format of the HTML being returned (eg. that there's no attributes on the `<body>`, that the sequences `<body>` and `</body>` isn't used in a comment in the middle of the page, etc).

Another still-quite-bad way is to write the whole document to the `innerHTML` of a newly-created `<div>` and fish out the elements you want, not caring that writing `<html>` or `<body>` inside a `<div>` is broken. You'll be unable to reliably separate the child elements of `<head>` from those in `<body>` this way, but this is what eg jQuery does.

A more robust but more painful way would be to use a separate HTML document:

```
var iframe= document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display= 'none';
document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
var idoc= 'contentDocument' in iframe? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
idoc.write(htmlpage);
idoc.close();
alert(idoc.body.innerHTML);
document.body.removeChild(iframe);
```

though this would also execute all scripts inside the document, potentially changing it, so that might not be satisfactory either.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML Page is on Web then You can use YQL.

e.g if your page url is http://xyz.com/page.html and you want everything in body element 
do like this

```
select * from html where url="http://xyz.com/page.html" and xpath='//body'
```

If you are new to YQL read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YQL_Page_Scraping

There is also simple way to do it using Chromyqlip Extension https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bkmllkjbfbeephbldeflbnpclgfbjfmn

Hope this will help You!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the XML object for the "body" tag from the XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject
// object (requestObj).

// NOTE: This assumes there is only one "body" tag in your HTML document.
var body = requestObj.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

// Get the "body" tag as an XML string.
var bodyXML;

// for Internet Explorer            
if (body.xml) {
    bodyXML = body.xml;
}

// for every other browser
if (typeof (XMLSerializer) != "undefined") {
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    bodyXML = serializer.serializeToString(body);
}
```

This gets you the XML for the "body" tag, as a string. Unfortunately, it still includes the "<body>" and "</body>", so if you want only the contents of the tag you will have to strip these off.

You might want to take a look at the second example ("Example HTML code 2") on [this page](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwwrcvr.php).